# Please remove/alter tags with slashes in them

Tags: support, tags, stack-exchange

I was going through and cleaning up some onesie tags on SO and discovered a `[wave/out]` tag.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to find the question tagged with that tag. The link from the Tag Search page doesn't work (the slash ends up escaped in the URL, but it still gives me a page not found), and putting the tag into the search box just strips out the slash, so I get results for `[waveout]`. Also, the tag doesn't even show up if you search for it using 'wave' as the search term!

All tags in the systems (all sites) with slashes need to be modified or eliminated. These will all be straggling tags up until the time the tag input was sanitized better, and I can't imagine they are numerous.

Obviously, I'd love to take care of this myself, but it doesn't look to be possible.

(I'm going to call this a support request since you can't create new tags with a slash in them -- although I just tried and the form just silently strips out the slash.)

Answer (score 2):

It was:

[Playing wave file ends immediately (C++, Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629/playing-wave-file-ends-immediatly-c-windows)

And it is now gone.

Hint: Google is very useful.

Comment: Thanks. Can that super-amazing-Google-thingy find other questions having tags with slashes?